# Webbrowser HTML files storage directory In a WinForms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to develop an application in Win-Forms with a local database which stores product names and prices.

I made a `SearchBox` and `DataGridView` for displaying products and a `WebBrowser` to display HTML files. This shows the product characteristics whenever the user clicks on the product through the `DataGridView`. I was thinking to store HTML files in a folder under resources in Visual Studio.

My problem is where will these HTML files be placed after installation by the user (both on x86 and x64 bits)? Because I need to point to the file directory each time the user clicks on a product in the grid view.
so here is the code for this

```
 public void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string Product_id;
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        RCP_id = row.Cells["ProductID"].Value.ToString();
        try
        {
            Browser1.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/ME/Documents/" + Product_id + ".html");

        catch
        {
            RCPBrowser.Navigate("file:///C:/Users/ME/Documents/default.html");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "where will these HTML files be placed after installation"   Why don't you try it and see?   You'll certainly want to use relative paths.

Comment: Why not put the source of the HTML files in the database as well? Any resources like images and fonts could be put to application resource RESX files. Will the database be read-only, or editable?

Comment: in the Browser1.Navigate() method i should point to the file directory that contains HTML files after installation because i want to retrieve these files from user's PC.
   @Steve i 'm pointing to the files in my PC, so what to do in order to point to a folder in the user's PC containing my HTML files ?
   Tomàs, this will be read-only, SQL based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put some resources within a Visual Studio project, the default is that the resource is included within the generated executable (exe or dll). You can access them from code using Resources.*nameOfTheResource*. No other file will be saved on the file system, so your problem is not actually a problem.

But in your case, storing HTML files as resources within the exe is not a good choice: you will not be able to let the browser navigate from one HTML to another.

Store the HTML files is *currentExeFolder* /Resources (or whatever folder name is appropriate) and deploy them together with your exe.

Answer (score 1):

The Ideal way is to place the file in the application folder.

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "//Filename.filetype");
```